# Capistrano and EC2: sh: 1: kill FAILED

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I am trying to deploy new code to Amazon EC2 instance with using capistrano and suddenly, I got this error:

```
servers: ["IP"]
[IP] executing command
*** [err :: IP] cat:
*** [err :: IP] /home/deployer/fileto/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
*** [err :: IP] : No such file or directory
*** [err :: IP]
*** [err :: IP] sh: 1: kill:
*** [err :: IP] Usage: kill [-s sigspec | -signum | -sigspec] [pid | job]... or
*** [err :: IP] kill -l [exitstatus]
*** [err :: IP]
    command finished in 371ms
failed: "sh -c 'kill -s USR2 `cat /home/deployer/project_name/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid`'" on IP
```

Two hours ago I deployed code successfully, but now I when I try it, I get this error message.

What happened with the instance and the whole deployment process if 2 hours ago was everything working well?

**EDIT:** When I run

*kill -s USR2 `cat /home/deployer/fileto/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid`*

I get

```
cat: /home/deployer/fileto/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid: No such file or directory
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
```

Comment: just to ensure...  create a `pids` folder inside `tmp`, if it not exists, then execute your command. also check file system permission so that this process can create `unicorn.pid` file when it runs.

Comment: The `pids` folder exists, how can I check the permissions?

Comment: `$ ls -ld directory` to check permission (check the file owner also)  and to provide write permission ex. `sudo chmod -R 777 tmp`

Comment: I just did it, but the result is unfortunately the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Is this an error condition that needs to stop deployment? You can add || true to the end of the kill command, add :on_error => continue to the task, or prefix with [ -d /home/deployer/fileto/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid ] before the kill command.